# Laravel API - Trying to forbid admins to delete a product if the product is ordered

Tags: laravel, api, controller, laravel-8, laravel-api

Like the title says, I'm trying to determine if the product is not ordered, otherwise the admin is able to remove the product. It seems to work, but I think I am not handling it the right way because the console returns an error 500.

*This is my destroy function in the* **ProductController**:

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $ordersLink = $product->orders()->where('orders.product_id', $product->id)->exists();

    if(!$ordersLink) {
        $status = $product->delete();
    } 

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $status ? 'Product removed' : 'Product not removed'
    ]); 
}
```

It is throwing an error when the product can't be deleted, but it should return 'Product not removed.'

Any help would be appreciated! Cheers

Comment: is the id of the order the same as id of the product?

Comment: Oh wait! You are correct, I'm blind. I corrected it, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: when you call  $product->orders(), if you have defined the relationships correctly, it already is looking for orders with that product id. when there is no order it cannot go to the next query ->where('orders.product_id', $product->id). you should check the exists on orders and next part is causing the error

Comment: if you want to check the orders yourslef then you should change $product->orders()->where('orders.product_id', $product->id)->exists(); to something like Order::where('orders.product_id', $product->id)->exists();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace code with following:

```
public function destroy(Product $product)
{
    $status = false;
    $ordersLink = $product->orders()->exists();

    if(!$ordersLink) {
        $status = $product->delete();
    } 

    return response()->json([
        'status' => $status,
        'message' => $status ? 'Product removed' : 'Product not removed'
    ]); 
}
```